# Use Microsoft Office 2013 interop dll in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, office-interop, excel-interop

Is it possible to use interop dll from Office 2013 in Sharepoint 2010 solutions? I need to use excel in my Sharepoint solution, but on server was installed Office 2013 and i cant chose Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Consider using Open XML SDK or any other third-party components instead.